# What is the difference between the Windows and System namespaces?

Tags: c#

In my C# app I usually see two main namespaces `System` and `Windows`, for example:

**System:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

**Windows:**

```
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
```

What is the difference between these two namespaces? Is there a logic division between them in terms of which .NET classes belong in which namespace?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. They are different because they contain different code?

Comment: They have different types within them...  Types in `System` are not platform-specific, while types in `Windows` are.

Comment: different forms that group classes and namespaces. Not clear what you ask.

Comment: Not just `System` and `Windows`, all those listed in your question differ from each other for a simple and only reason mentioned by @DStanley and @Seth. Flagged for closing.

Comment: See [`Windows` namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454041.aspx) and [`System` Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: What I mean is, how are those classes structured into those two namespaces?

Comment: What do you mean, how they're structured?

Comment: For example, why is a class in one namespace and not the other? Given that they are two main biggest namespaces, I want to know the role of each one.

Comment: See my answer (and @DStanley's comment). The `Windows` namespace is for Windows-only code; the `System` namespace is for platform-independent code.

Comment: Maybe it could have been worded better, but I think it's a good and clear question.... he wants to know why there are 2 separate namespaces; if there's a logic division between them in terms of which .Net classes belong in which.

Comment: There's no rule as to why classes go into particular namespaces - the designer of the class chooses a namespace that makes sense for the purpose of the class.  It has no impact on security, accessibility, or functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### From MSDN

- [`Windows` namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454041.aspx) (emphasis mine):

  > The `Windows` namespaces (`Windows.Foundation`, `Windows.UI`, `Windows.UI.Xaml`, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives`, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media`, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation`, and `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Media3D`) contain types for managing the user interface of your application.
  >
  > ...The types in the Windows namespaces [are] included in .NET for **Windows 8.x Store apps**. Note that the .NET for Windows 8.x Store apps do not include all the members of each type. For information about individual types, see the linked topics. The documentation for a type indicates which members are included in the .NET for Windows 8.x Store apps.
- [`System` Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  > The `System` namespace contains fundamental classes and base classes that define commonly-used value and reference data types, events and event handlers, interfaces, attributes, and processing exceptions.

### Answer

To answer your question, the types in the `Windows` namespace are for **Windows only**; those in `System` are platform-independent (as @DStanley points out in the comments).

Note that C# can be run on different platforms than Windows - for example, using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) (for Linux) or [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/) (for iOS or Android, etc.).

Comment: Is the `Windows` namespace just for Windows 8? What about Windows 7 or 10?

Comment: According to the MSDN link, it seems to be just Windows 8, though I image this is an old article. As of Windows 8, Microsoft completely changed the way the UI worked in Windows - the inclusion of ['apps' and the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps-and-games) came with it. Windows 10 continues this way of working - as such, the `Windows` namespaces will (probably) apply to apps in Windows 10.

Comment: Namespace is purely for the organization of types and has no impact on accessibility or functionality.  YOU could create a class and put it in the `Windows` namespace, but it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: @DStanley - I am aware of that. It'd be **rather** dirty, but there there's no reason I couldn't have all my code in the `System` or `Windows` namespaces (e.g. `System.Person`, `Windows.Employee`, etc. I'm not trying to say that the namespaces are prescriptive; they are there entirely for the developer's sake: obfuscators often lump all the code in a solution into a single namespace even.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Sorry, I was answering's Chin's question, not yours.  It seems like the OP believes there's some sort of consequence or added functionality based on what namespace a class is in, which is not the case.  It's purely for organization.

Comment: @DStanley - whoops - I should have realised you weren't addressing  me.

Comment: @Chin - does this answer your question?